# Deletar perfil apenas no SOen

Tags: suporte

Postei uma pergunta como deletar meu perfil no stackoverflow(Inglês) e estou recebendo no SOpt. Eu quero deletar apenas no Inglês e não aqui, agora me confundiu tudo. Estou receoso em deletar e deletar o meu perfil no SOpt. Gostaria de uma orientação a respeito.

Comment: [Como deletar uma conta?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1525/91)

Comment: Sim, mas apenas no site desejado e parece que se eu deletar, vai deletar aqui no SOpt e não é o que eu quero.

Comment: Onde diz isso? vc deve entrar em contato pelo link no rodapé do site onde deseja remover o usuário, preencher o formulário, selecione a opção `I need to delete my user profile` lá explique o motivo.

Comment: @rray acho que o pnet já fez esse pedido, e recebeu uma resposta aqui no sopt e está com medo que dizer que "sim" porque pode apagar a daqui também. Estou certo pnet?

Comment: O que você recebeu no SOpt?

Comment: Eu postei no SOen e recebi o comentário em português de como fazer pelo SOpt. Isso me deixou confuso

Comment: A notificação é *network wide*, então você recebe na rede e não no SOpt, claro que se está no SOpt no momento a mensagem escolhida será a traduzida. Acredito que a exclusão está em curso, se fez corretamente, vai excluir a conta correta, as contas são independentes, até onde eu sei.

Comment: Ok, valeu @bigown. Vou continuar o processo.

Comment: @pnet leia com atenção as mensagens, veja se está indicando o número de usuário certo, se tiver dúvida, se recebeu um e-mail, veja se pode respondê-lo. Não posso falar com toda certeza porque nunca vi isso funcionando, nunca removi conta minha :)

Comment: Ok, @bigown, vou verificar. Estamos com problemas desde ontem na nossa Internet aqui na empresa e quando estabilizar, eu vou ver isso sim.